# Call a rest WS and get: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Tags: javascript, html, web-services

I called a rest WS from my html page and I wanna get the json response:

I tried the following code:

```
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest){ xmlhttpp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }else{
  xmlhttpp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); 
  }
  xmlhttpp.open("GET","http://localhost:8080/myApp/services/userService/getUser/1");
  xmlhttpp.send();

  var json = xmlhttpp.responseText,
  obj = JSON.parse(json);
  alert('json'+obj.email);
```

But I get thar error:

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
```

NB: This ws returns:

```
{"active":"true","email":"USER1@gmail.com","id":"1","userName":"USER1"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that as of when you tried to parse it, `json` (`xmlhttpp.responseText`) was blank. XHR calls are (by default) *asynchronous*. `send` *starts* the call, but then your code continues while the call is happening.

To use the result, you use a `readystatechange` handler:

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    xmlhttpp = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else {
    xmlhttpp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttpp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    var json, obj;
    if (xmlhttpp.readyState === 4) {
        if (xmlhttpp.status === 200) {
            json = xmlhttpp.responseText;
            obj = JSON.parse(json);
            alert('json' + obj.email);
        } else {
            alert('the call failed');
        }
    }
};
xmlhttpp.open("GET", "http://localhost:8080/myApp/services/userService/getUser/1");

xmlhttpp.send();
// ...and code here runs **before** the call completes...
```

`readyState` `4` is "done", and then we check the HTTP status code of the result (200 = all is good).

---

While it's technically possible (for now) to make XHR work synchronously (`send` doesn't return until the call is complete), it makes for a poor user experience, locking up the UI of the browser. So I haven't shown it here, but if you look at the [XMLHttpRequest documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/), it's there.

Comment: I tried your code, but I get : the call failed :
THE xmlhttpp.status = 0

Comment: @neila: Then you're dealing with a [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) problem. My guess is your page is loaded from port `80` (the default HTTP port), but I can see that you're loading the JSON from port `8080`. That's a cross-origin call. If you control both sides, you may be able to use [Cross Origin Resource Sharing](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/), provided the browsers you're targeting [support it](http://caniuse.com/#feat=cors). Note that in IE8 and 9, CORS is supported, but not via `XMLHttpRequest` (you have to use M$'s `XDomainRequest` instead).

Comment: I am experiencing the same error as OP but my JSON.parse(this.responseText); is within my readystatechange lisener and the readyState is 4 before it attempts to parse it.  Any other reason this error could occur?

Comment: @mgrenier: LOok at `this.responseText`. My guess is it's `null`.

Comment: it isn't null...when it is empty though I get an "unexpected end of data..." error when echo anything (contents do not seem to matter) I get "unexpected character at line 1..." error.

Comment: I realize now, if I want to echo anything I have to do it like so "echo json_encode('some text');" which then gives me an "unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data" error